# ASP.NET Core MVC Appending FormData with image only shows form data or the image passed not both

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, form-data

Goal: Send image and form data from on button press to controller.

Issue: When sending the image and form data, only the image will be passed. But not both.

I don't think it's the Data.append() because if I remove it, it sends nothing.

But if I use this, then it just

> ```
>   var data = new FormData(this);
>   data.append("ThumbnailImageFile", thumbnail[0]);
> ```

then it errors out and doesn't even post.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

I've run out of ideas at this point. Please shoot me some ideas! Thanks!

View:

```
@model AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Admin.AddWebProductModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductAdd";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .PreviewImageThingy{
        height: 10em;
    }
</style>

<h2>Add a Product</h2>
<link href="~/css/Chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/Chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.IntWebProductId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.BlnIsDeleted)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.DteCreated)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product)


        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Product Name</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.StrProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.StrProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Tags</h5>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @* Stuff here *@
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(Model => Model.product.SelectedIDArray, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TagsList, "IntWebTagId", "StrTagName"), new { @class = "chzn-select", multiple = "multiple" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Thumbnail Image</h5>

            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input type="file" id="Thumbnailbrowse">
                <div id="imgPreview" class="thumbnail" style="display:none">
                    <img class="img-responsive PreviewImageThingy" id="targetImg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <a href="#" onclick="ClearPreview()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                        <span id="description"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Images</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <h5>Upload Images</h5>
                <input type="file" multiple id="Item-Gallary-photo-add">
                <div class="gallery"></div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Is Product Active?</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.BlnIsActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.BlnIsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Featured Item</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.BlnIsFeatured)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.BlnIsFeatured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                List<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.InventoryItemList;
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Inventory System Item</h5>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.product.IntItemId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.IntItemId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>MSRP</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.DecMsrp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.DecMsrp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Description</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.StrDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.StrDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Specs</h5>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Static Pressure in Inches w.g.</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrStaticPressureIn)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Air Volume (CFM)</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrCfm)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Noise (sones)</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrNoise)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Fan Watts</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrWatts)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Duct Diameter</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrDiameter)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Power Rating</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrPowerRating)</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UploadForm()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen(
            { width: "100%" });
    });



    // Thumbnail
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Thumbnailbrowse").change(function () {

            var File = this.files;

            if (File && File[0]) {
                ReadImage(File[0]);
            }

        })


    })


    var ReadImage = function (file) {

        var reader = new FileReader;
        var image = new Image;

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function (_file) {

            image.src = _file.target.result;
            image.onload = function () {

                var height = this.height;
                var width = this.width;
                var type = file.type;
                var size = ~~(file.size / 1024) + "KB";

                $("#targetImg").attr('src', _file.target.result);
                $("#description").text("Size:" + size + ", " + height + "X " + width + ", " + type + "");
                $("#imgPreview").show();

            }

        }

    }

    var ClearPreview = function () {
        $("#Thumbnailbrowse").val('');
        $("#description").text('');
        $("#imgPreview").hide();

    }

    // Gallary
    $(function () {
        // Multiple images preview in browser
        var imagesPreview = function (input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

            if (input.files) {
                var filesAmount = input.files.length;

                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview).addClass("PreviewImageThingy");
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }

        };

        $('#Item-Gallary-photo-add').on('change', function () {
            imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
        });
    });


    var UploadForm = function () {

        var thumbnail = $("#Thumbnailbrowse").get(0).files;
        
        var data = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
        data.append("ThumbnailImageFile", thumbnail[0]);
        

        $.ajax({

            type: "Post",
            url: "/admin/ProductAdd",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });

    };


</script>
```

Model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Admin
{
    public class AddWebProductModel
    {

        public TwebProduct product { get; set; }

        public IFormFile ThumbnailImageFile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductAdd(AddWebProductModel tbl)
{
//Bunch of junk
}
```

[[image: The data passed1]

Here's the TwebProduct model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

#nullable disable

namespace AirmotionEcommerceWebsite
{
    public partial class TwebProduct
    {
        public TwebProduct()
        {
            TwebCartProducts = new HashSet<TwebCartProduct>();
            TwebOrderProducts = new HashSet<TwebOrderProduct>();
            TwebProductImages = new HashSet<TwebProductImage>();
            TwebProductTags = new HashSet<TwebProductTag>();
        }

        public int IntWebProductId { get; set; }
        public int IntWebTagId { get; set; }
        public int IntCompanyId { get; set; }
        public string StrProductName { get; set; }
        public bool BlnIsActive { get; set; }
        public bool BlnIsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool BlnIsFeatured { get; set; }
        public int IntItemId { get; set; }
        public decimal DecMsrp { get; set; }
        public DateTime DteCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DteModified { get; set; }
        public string StrDescription { get; set; }
        public string StrDetailedSpecs { get; set; }
        public string VarThumbnailImage { get; set; }
        public string StrStaticPressureIn { get; set; }
        public string StrCfm { get; set; }
        public string StrNoise { get; set; }
        public string StrWatts { get; set; }
        public string StrDiameter { get; set; }
        public string StrPowerRating { get; set; }

        public virtual Tcompany IntCompany { get; set; }
        public virtual Titem IntItem { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TwebCartProduct> TwebCartProducts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TwebOrderProduct> TwebOrderProducts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TwebProductImage> TwebProductImages { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TwebProductTag> TwebProductTags { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<string> SelectedIDArray { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int QuantityToCart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the version of asp.net core:

```
Display .NET Core information.
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.400
 Commit:    d61950f9bf

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.9
  Commit:  208e377a53

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Can you show your model `TwebProduct `? By the way,What is your Asp.Net core version?

Comment: @XinranShen Here's the version information about what asp.net core version I'm using. Not sure which one you wanted. So I added it to the main post

Comment: I copy your code in my VS,  It works and I can  receive both the image and form data , I don't know why you can only receive the image.